Determining Parameter Values for a Set of Solutions Involving Absolute Value Equations
The problem in the textbook asks the following:

At what values of the parameter "$a$" does the set of solutions to the equation $|x - 1| + |x - a| = 1 - a$ consist of three integers?

I couldn't solve the problem on my own for quite a while, so I looked up the answer in the textbook, and it is:

$-2 < a ≤ -1$.

The textbook also gives a hint on how to approach the problem, suggesting to use geometrical interpretation. Yet I can't seem to understand how to get to the correct solution.
I've attempted several different ways of solving, but here's the one that makes the most sense to me:
1) There's three cases in total: 
Note that "$a$" can never be >1, because otherwise there's no valid solutions for the equation, hence: 
(1) $x>= 1, a <= 1 \implies$ (The values in both of the modules $|x - 1|$, $|x - a|$ are positive), 
(2.1) $x<1,$ and $a < x \implies$ (The value in the module $|x - 1|$ is negative, and in $|x - a|$ is positive), 
(2.2) $x<1,$ and $a >= x \implies$ (The value in the module $|x - 1|$ is negative, and in $|x - a|$ is negative)
(1) $
  \begin{cases}
    x ≥ 1, \\ 
    a ≤ 1, \\
    x - 1 + x - a = 1 - a \implies 2x - 2 = 0 \implies x = 1 
  \end{cases} 
  \implies 
  \begin{cases} 
    a ≤ 1, \\
    x = 1 
  \end{cases}
  $
(2.1) $
  \begin{cases}
    x < 1, \\
    a \leq 1, \\
    1 - x + x - a = 1 - a \implies 1 - a = 1 - a, \quad \text{when} \space a < x, \\
  \end{cases} 
    \implies 
  \begin{cases}
    x < 1, \\
    a \leq 1, \\
    x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \text{when} \space a < x, \\
  \end{cases} 
  $
(2.2) $
  \begin{cases}
    x < 1, \\
    a \leq 1, \\
    1 - x - x + a = 1 - a \implies −2x=−2a , \quad \text{when} \space a \ge x, \\
  \end{cases} 
    \implies 
  \begin{cases}
    x < 1, \\
    a \leq 1, \\
    x = a, \quad \text{when} \quad a \ge x \\
  \end{cases} 
  $
2) Let a coordinate system be the geometrical interpretation, and in this case "$a$" parameter equates to the value of the function, so the final drawing consist of 3 linear graphs.
That's all. After drawing the graphs I don't have the actual answer. Also I am little confused about the way the three final systems of equations($1$, $2.1$, $2.2$) look -- it looks as if they can be simplified further.
Any assistance in understanding the correct method to approach this problem and how to interpret the systems of equations appropriately within the geometrical context, so as any additional insights or explanations would be of great help. Thanks!

Strange. I've done my computations and I've concluded that $\lvert x-1\rvert+\lvert x-a\rvert=1-a\Leftrightarrow a\le x\le 1$. Therefore I would say that the set of solutions is never a set of three integers.

@SassatelliGiulio try any number from the range $(-2;-1]$ for the "$a$" parameter, and the set of solutions of the equation does indeed consist of three integers. I just don't understand what I am doing wrong, because I obviously am :)

I don't believe me doing what you suggest is going to bring anything new to the table.

Does the book specify that $x$ must be an integer.

@SassatelliGiulio that's because of the triangle inequality.  If $x < a\le 1$ then $1-x > 1-a$  and if $a \le 1 < x$ then $x-a > 1-a$ which both lead to imediate contradictions.  But if $a\le x \le 1$ then $1-a = (1-x)+(x-a)$.  (And we know $a\le 1$ because $1-a=|x-1| + |x-1| \ge 0 + 0 =0$.)

... or maybe the text used the word "contains"?

$1-a = |x-1| + |x-a| \ge 0$ so $a \le 1$.
Now by the triangle inequality we have $1-a= |1-a| \le |1-x| + |x-a|$ with equality holding if and only if $a\le x \le 1$.
So if the solution set has $3$ integers (and presumably an infinite number of real non-integers--- this is the only way I can interpret "consists of three integers" to make any meaningful sense) then
We must have the interval the solution set, $[a, 1]$, span three consecutive integers but not $4$.  Now $1$ must be in the set and be the largest integer in the solutions set. so the other two integers must be $0$ and $-1$. And we can not include $-2$.
So $-2 < a \le -1$.
That, I believe, is how the text intended you to do it.
But.... I must say, if so, that book abused the meaning of the word "consist" (A better word would be "contain").... unless the book somewhere specified that $x$ must be an integer.
=====
P.S.  The triangle inequality holds that $||p - q||$, the distance between any two points must be less than or equal to $||p-x|| + ||x-p||$ for any $x$.  It's called the triangle inequality because it litterally says the distance between two points the measure of the straight line between them and is less than taking a third point, making a triangle and going along the distance of the two other sides.
Now $||p-q|| \le ||p-x|| + ||x-p||$ we have equality hold if and only if the third point is colinear and between $p$ and $q$.
In two dimensions this is easy to geometry intuition but in a 1 dimension (the real number line) it may not seems so geometric as all numbers are colinear.
But we can see that if $p< q$ then $|q-p| \le |q-x| + |x-p|$ will always hold but equality will only hold if $p\le x \le q$.
If $x < p < q$ then $q-x > q-p$ and so $|q-x| + |x-p| \ge |q-x| > |q-p|$.
And if $p < q < x$ then $x-p > q-p$ and so $|q-x| + |x-p| \ge |x-p| > |q-p|$.
But if $p \le x \le q$ then $|q-p| =q-p= (q-x) + (x-p) = |q-x| +|x-p|$.
